# Where is the 2nd. battery in my 2016 Chevy Malibu

Tags: battery, chevrolet, malibu

Where is the 2nd battery if I have one. My friends Chevy truck has it under back seat.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you looked in the owner's manual? Does the vehicle even _have_ a second battery?

Comment: Is your Malibu a hybrid model or not? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

2nd battery? Most passenger vehicles only have one battery. Most hybrid vehicles will have two, with a high voltage one (the big one) which powers the electric motor, and a 12v (standard vehicle battery) which runs the electronics. I know there was a Hybrid model for the 2016 Malibu, but if yours has just the internal combustion engine, it would only have one battery. Some pickups may have two batteries, but those are far/few between. Semi trucks may have four batteries (or more).

**UPDATE:**

I was doing some reading online and come to find out, *some* of the 2016 (8th Generation - 2013-2016) Malibu's came with an auxiliary battery which assisted with the stop/start. It depends on which generation of Malibu you had. If it is an 8th Gen, the aux battery would be in the trunk. I don't know for sure, but would bet it would be on the right hand side as you're looking at the trunk, under some kind of removable cover. It is my understanding they removed the aux battery for the 9th Gen models (2016 and newer). This only applies to the non-Hybrid models. I personally could not tell you how to differentiate between the two generations. Maybe someone can comment and give the information.

Comment: Some folks who do remote camping may have an auxiliary battery tucked away somewhere (like on my Tacoma), but that seems unlikely for a Malibu...

Comment: @JonCuster - Exactly. Unless the Malibu the OP owns is a hybrid model, there normally would not be a 2nd battery.

Comment: @Paulster2 - and it actually turns out there were 2016 Malibu hybrids - a bit surprised at that. The OP should clarify I think.

Comment: @JonCuster - Some more unknown information added ... crazy.